# Is it possible to build and use libpam in building rstudio server without a root?

Tags: compiling, pam, rstudio

I need to build an RStudio server for my account on HPC. RStudio is not provided by the system, and I have no root privileges (and there is no support for docker/singularity).

One of the dependencies of the RStudio is libpam.

Is it possible to build libpam in such way, that it is usable by the rstudio, all without root priviledges?

Answer (score 0):

The libpam module is owned by root but is executable/usable by anyone so you shouldn't have any issues there. A bigger concern is how you are going to modify other settings or even install RStudio Server without the rights of root.